# How can I make this code work for BigIntegers ? This code is about finding largest prime factor of a number(n)

Tags: java

```
public class E2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         long  i,f,n=12345,p=1,j;
        for(i=2;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(n%i==0)
            {
                f=i;
                for( j=2;j<=f/2;j++)
                {
                    if(f%j==0)
                        break;
                    else
                        continue;   
                }j--;
                if(j==f/2)
                    p=f;
            }
            else
            {continue;}
        }
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

here , n is a random number whose largest prime number is to find . The code works for long,integers. I first applied a for loop to find a factor of n and check for the factor to be prime or not ,if they are prime they get stored in p thus last value of p is the largest prime factor.

Comment: Have you tried to use `BigInteger`? If yes, where have you failed? Have you read the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)?

Comment: yes I tried BigInteger and I got stuck when I needed to divide and find mod of  BifInteger in a loop(repeatedly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is very inefficient, if you need to tackle larger numbers, that don't fit into a long, you also need to use a better algorithm.

The following program still only works for `long` but is much more efficient. It is however still not efficient enough to go much beyond the range of `long`. Note that for every two digits you add, the worst case run time increases by a factor of 10.

Compare the runtime with your approach for the given test cases. Or take some smaller numbers like `1234567890L` if you don't want to wait so long.

It works by dividing out the smaller prime factors, and avoids therefore the need to check if a factor found is prime because smaller factors would have been found before.

After checking factors up to sqrt(n) the remaining unsplit piece n must be prime (or 1). This is because otherwise one of the prime factors must be smaller or equal to sqrt(n) and thus would have been found before.

Actually, it would be enough to make trial divisions only with prime numbers but since we don't have a list the compromise taken here is to make 2 a special case and then only try odd numbers. This speeds up the algorithm by a factor of 2 compared to the simple version.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long n = 1234567890123456789L;
        System.out.printf("largest prime factor of %d is %d%n", n, largestPrimeFactorOf(n));
        n = 1234567890123456791L;
        System.out.printf("largest prime factor of %d is %d%n", n, largestPrimeFactorOf(n));
        n = 1234567890123456797L;
        System.out.printf("largest prime factor of %d is %d%n", n, largestPrimeFactorOf(n));
        n = 1234567890123456817L;
        System.out.printf("largest prime factor of %d is %d%n", n, largestPrimeFactorOf(n));
        n = 4611686014132420609L;
        System.out.printf("largest prime factor of %d is %d%n", n, largestPrimeFactorOf(n));
    }

    public static long largestPrimeFactorOf(long n) {
        long last = 1;
        while (n % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.printf("prime factor 2 found%n");
            n /= 2;
            last = 2;
        }
        for (long t = 3; t * t <= n; t += 2) {
            while (n % t == 0) {
                System.out.printf("prime factor %d found%n", t);
                n /= t;
                last = t;
            }
        }
        return n == 1 ? last : n;
    }
}
```

The output of this program is

```
prime factor 3 found
prime factor 3 found
prime factor 101 found
prime factor 3541 found
prime factor 3607 found
prime factor 3803 found
largest prime factor of 1234567890123456789 is 27961
prime factor 7 found
prime factor 164005957 found
largest prime factor of 1234567890123456791 is 1075368509
prime factor 38429233 found
largest prime factor of 1234567890123456797 is 32125748909
largest prime factor of 1234567890123456817 is 1234567890123456817
prime factor 2147483647 found
prime factor 2147483647 found
largest prime factor of 4611686014132420609 is 2147483647
```

Comment: Yes this code is really efficient, I appreciate your help!

Comment: @DavidWallace technically yes, because I felt the original question was an instance of the XY problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem and the real question is "How can I make it work for larger numbers"

Comment: I doubt it.  OP says his/her original algorithm works for `long`s.  What he/she wants to know is how to do the arithmetic operations (such as `mod` and so on) with the `BigInteger` class.  You've improved on the algorithm that OP was using, but you haven't answered the question.